# when open the page,why can't hide the content?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have added the **Prototype** library to my site, then add the following code.when i open the page, i want to all the content in the ul are hidden.

```
 Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
   $$('.block-category li.parent ul').hide() //why this line doesn't work
    $$('.block-category li.parent > a span').each(function (element) {
        element.observe('click', function (e) {
            e.element().up().next('ul').toggle();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
    <div class="block block-category">
    <li class="level-top  parent">
    <a href="example.com/...."><span>text one</span></a>
    <ul> //the 1 ul
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="level-top"><a href="..."><span>....</span></a></li>


  <li class="level-top  parent">
    <a href="example.com/...."><span>text two</span></a>
    <ul> //the 2 ul
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>
  <li class="level-top  parent">
    <a href="example.com/...."><span>text three</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </div>
```

thank you.

Comment: use $$('.block-category > li > ul').hide();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$$()` method returns a list of elements that match that CSS selector - if you want to iterate over them and run the same method use the `invoke()` method

```
$$('.block-category li.parent ul').invoke('hide');
$$('.block-category li.parent ul').invoke('observe','click',function(){
     alert('element was clicked');
});
```

If you need to do more than just run a single method use the `each()` method

```
$$('.block-category li.parent ul').each(function(item){
    item.hide();
    //item.update('new content');
    //etc
});
```

Comment: could i need put the code in Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {...? if i want to run the code when the page loaded. like document.ready. how do i do?

Comment: yes you can put this inside that observer - typically I use `document.observe("dom:loaded",function(){  });` as this will fire when the DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

Try this, seams that hide cannot applied to a set of elements directly:

```
$$('.block-category li.parent ul').each(function(elm) {
   elm.hide();
});
```